# How to keep the hover effect when moving the cursor over the tooltip?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a popup form that pops up when hovering over a div. When I hover over the div, a form appears, and when I start typing username or password, the browser offers a saved version of the data for this site as a tooltip. And when I hover over this option, the form disappears. How can I solve this problem?
[image: Tooltip]

```js
$(".open-popup-btn").on("mouseenter", function() {
  $(this).addClass("active");
})

$(".popup-form").on("mouseleave", function() {
  $(".open-popup-btn").removeClass("active");
})
```

```css
.open-popup-btn {
  position: relative width: 200px;
}

.popup-form {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
}

.open-popup-btn.active .popup-form {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="open-popup-btn">
  OPEN
  <div class="popup-form">
    <form>
      <input type="text" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's some terrible ux to only show the form if the mouse is in the correct place

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden checkbox; generally speaking, this is a much safer and better way comparing to hover. Moreover, JavaScript isn't even needed.

```css
#open-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

#open-checkbox:checked + .popup-form {
  display: block;
}
```

Try it:

```css
.open-popup-btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.popup-form {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}

#open-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

#open-checkbox:checked + .popup-form {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="open-popup-btn">
  <label for="open-checkbox">
    OPEN
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="open-checkbox">
  
  <div class="popup-form">
    <form>
      <input type="text" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I need exactly the hover effect for the popup